# How to replace specific characters with corresponding characters in java?

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to do something like this: Replace all `ck` with `k` and all `dd` with `wr` and all `f` with `m` and 10 more replacements like this.
I can do it with `replace("ck","k").replace("dd","wr")`and so on, but it seams silly and it is slow. Is there any function in java that does something like this?
for example `replace(string,stringArray1, stringArray2);`

Comment: What's wrong with this approach?  I think it's a lot easier to read than what you're proposing.

Comment: this is an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1010945/3959856

Comment: @JoeC perhaps, but it will iterate the string as many times as number of rules for replacement.

Comment: @JackFlamp Thanks, but that was not what i asked. Anyway, it had slipped my mind to use stringbuilders.

Comment: @JackFlamp StringBuilder doesnt seem to have the replace function, as described above.

Comment: Ok new try :) I am not sure about this one but here is another answer that might be interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1326962/3959856

Comment: ..or this kinda looks like your suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/13698843/3959856

Answer (score 2):

Use an [`appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) loop.

Here is a general purpose way to do it:

```
private static String replace(String input, Map<String, String> mappings) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(toRegex(mappings.keySet())).matcher(input);
    while (m.find())
        m.appendReplacement(buf, Matcher.quoteReplacement(mappings.get(m.group())));
    return m.appendTail(buf).toString();
}
private static String toRegex(Collection<String> keys) {
    return keys.stream().map(Pattern::quote).collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
}
```

If you're not using Java 8+, the second method would be:

```
private static String toRegex(Collection<String> keys) {
    StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder();
    for (String key : keys) {
        if (regex.length() != 0)
            regex.append("|");
        regex.append(Pattern.quote(key));
    }
    return regex.toString();
}
```

*Test code*

```
Map<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<>();
mappings.put("ck","k");
mappings.put("dd","wr");
mappings.put("f", "m");
System.out.println(replace("odd flock", mappings)); // prints: owr mlok
```

See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/DlGOTD) for running version.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, String> replacementMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
replacementMap.put("ck", "k");
replacementMap.put("dd", "wr");
replacementMap.put("f", "m");
// ...

String resultStr = "Abck fdddk wr fmck"; // whatever string to process
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(resultStr); // wrap it in builder

Iterator<String> iterator = replacementMap.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String strToReplace = iterator.next();
    replaceAll(builder, strToReplace, replacementMap.get(strToReplace));
}
System.out.println("Result is: " + builder.toString());

public static void replaceAll(StringBuilder builder, String from, String to) {
    int index = builder.indexOf(from);
    while (index != -1) {
        builder.replace(index, index + from.length(), to);
        index += to.length(); // Move to the end of the replacement
        index = builder.indexOf(from, index);
    }
}
```

The replaceAll() method was borrowed from this [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3472705/2078494)

Alternative to replaceAll() int his example is to use apache commons library, there is [StrBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StrBuilder.html) class which provides replaceAll() method. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28198285/2078494)