# Java the best and fastest way to edit text file

Tags: java, string, replace, text-files, edit

I need to edit a lot of text files effectively and fast! What is the best thing I can do?
I already come up with this function:

```
private boolean edit(File source)
{
    if (!source.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".java")) //Java text files only
        return false;

    String l, str = "", orig = ""; 
    try
    {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(source));
        while ((l = r.readLine()) != null)
        {
            orig = str += l+"\n";
        }
        r.close();

        for (Entry<String, String> e : mappings.entrySet()) //Replacing string by HashMap mappings!
            str = fastReplace(str, e.getKey(), e.getValue()); //Faster alterntive to String#replaceAll
        
        if (!str.equals(orig))
        {   
            BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(source));
            bf.write(str);  
            
            bf.close();
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        doLog(e.toString()); //Logging exception but unimportant for us...
    }
    return false;
}
```

I found my function a little bit clumsy because it first needs to read text file into string then edit it and write it back after that. So the question is. Is there any better and faster way to edit text file? I mean for example without necessity to turning it into string and then writing it back. For example is there a way to edit file directly as a text file or writing it without overriding the same unchanged parts of the file or any faster way to read and write file? Or is my function actually already fastest as it can be? 
In case somebody is wondering what my "fastReplace" function does then check this [Faster alternatives to replace method in a Java String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010928/faster-alternatives-to-replace-method-in-a-java-string) but I do not think it is important.

Comment: This is the point you consider a database over flatfiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to replace a string by another one of the exact same size byte for byte, then you could read the data sequentially in chunks with multiple block size, replace the desired spots and write the data back if a change has been made. If no change was made then there is no need to write back the block. In the best scenario, you will save few I/O operations, at the cost of significant code complexity.

If your editing is more complex and involves string insertions, then you have no way out of reading and writing back the entire text.

Early optimization is a bad idea. Source code files hardly span a single block and in your case you will probably save no time or space.

Comment: I need to replaceAll... replace the key from the map by its value!